# Can you using joins with direct path inserts?

Tags: oracle, direct-path

I have tried to find examples but they are all simple with a single where clause.  Here is the situation.  I have a bunch of legacy data transferred from another database.  I also have the "good" tables in that same database.  I need to transfer (data-conversion) data from the legacy tables to thew tables.  Because this is a different set of tables the data-conversion requires complex joins to put the old data into the new tables correctly.

So, old tables old data.

New tables must have the old data but it requires lots of joins to get that old data into the new tables correctly.

Can I use direct path with lots of joins like this?  INSERT SELECT (lots of joins)
Does direct path apply to tables that are already on the same database (transfer between tables)?  Is it only for loading tables from say a text file?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The query in your SELECT can be as complex as you'd like with a direct-path insert.  The direct-path refers only to the destination table.  It has nothing to do with the way that data is read or processed.

If you're doing a direct-path insert, you're asking Oracle to insert the new data above the high water mark of the table so you bypass the normal code that reuses space in existing blocks for new rows to be inserted.  It also has to block other inserts since you can't have the high water mark of the table change during a direct-path insert.  This probably isn't a big deal if you've got a downtime window in which to do the load but it would be quite problematic if you wanted the existing tables to be available for other applications during the load.

Answer (score 2):

No, on the contrary, it means you need to do a backup after a NOLOGGING load, not that you can't backup the database.

Allow me to elaborate a bit.  Normally, when you do DML in Oracle, the before images of the changes you are are making get logged in UNDO, and all the changes (including the UNDO changes) are first written to REDO.  This is how Oracle manages transactions, instance recovery, and database recovery.  If a transaction is aborted or rolled back, Oracle uses the information in UNDO to undo the changes your transaction made.  If the instance crashes, then on instance restart, Oracle will use the information in REDO and UNDO to recover up to the last committed transaction.  First, Oracle will read the REDO and roll forward, then, use UNDO to roll back all the transactions that were not committed at the time of the crash.  In this way, Oracle is able to recover up to the last committed transaction.

Now, when you specify an APPEND hint on an insert statement, Oracle will execute the INSERT with direct load.  This means that data is loaded into brand new, never before used blocks, from above the highwater mark.  Because the blocks being loaded are brand new, there is no "before image", so, Oracle can avoid writing UNDO, which improves performance.  If the database is in NOARCHIVELOG mode, then Oracle will also not write REDO.  On a database in ARCHIVELOG mode, Oracle will still write REDO, unless, before you do the insert /*+ append */, you set the table to NOLOGGING, (i.e. alter table tab_name nologging;).  In that case, REDO logging is disabled for the table.  However, this is where you could run into backup/recovery implications.  If you do a NOLOGGING direct load, and then you suffer a media failure, *and* the datafile containing the segment with the nologging operation is restored from a backup taken before the nologging load, then the redo log will *not* contain the changes required to recover that segment.  So, what happens?  Well, when you do a NOLOGGING load, Oracle writes extent invaldation records to the redo log, instead of the actual changes.  Then, if you use that redo in recovery, those data blocks will be marked logically corrupt.  Any subsequent queries against that segment will get an ORA-26040 error.

So, how to avoid this?  Well, you should always take a backup imediately following any NOLOGGING direct load.  If you restore/recover from a backup taken *after* the nologging load, there is no problem, because the data will be in the datablocks in the file that was restored.

Hope that's clear,

-Mark

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there should not be any arbitrary limits on query complexity.

If you do
insert /*+ APPEND */ into target_table select .... from source1, source2..., sourceN where

It should work fine.  Consider though, that the performance of the load will be limited by the performance of that query, so, be sure it's well-tuned, if you're expecting good performance.

Finally, consider whether setting NOLOGGING on the target table would improve performance significantly.  But, also consider the backup recovery implications, if you decide to implement NOLOGGING.

Hope that helps,

-Mark

Comment: Does that mean I can never backup the database or something?  sorry I didn't understand.